# How to use enum in structure C++

Tags: c++, struct, enums

I am trying to use enum within a structure, but I am getting the following error:

```
union.cpp:27:21: error: ‘DOLLAR’ was not declared in this scope
 book.currency = DOLLAR;
                 ^
```

here is my code:

```
 struct shelf{
      char title[50];
      char author[50];
      union {
          float dollars;
          int yens;
      };
 
      enum {
          DOLLAR = 1, YEN
      } currency;
  } book;
 
  int main () {
      strcpy(book.title,"book 1");
      strcpy(book.author, "author 1");
 
      book.dollars = 100;
 
      book.currency = DOLLAR;
 
      cout << book.currency;
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: It's defined only inside struct shelf

Comment: Use `shelf::DOLLAR` or declare `enum currency_enum` outside of `struct shelf` and then make ` currency_enum currency` in the struct shelf;

Comment: Avoid using `ALLCAPS`, as that is conventionally used for `#define` tokens.

Answer (score 5):

```
book.currency = DOLLAR;
```

should be

```
book.currency = shelf::DOLLAR;
```